# How to override spring's import annotation

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. In the main class annotated with @SpringBootApplication, I have imported some configurations, using the import annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ MyConfiguration.class })
public class MySpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MySpringBootApp.class).build().run(args);
    }
}
```

Now when I run my junit test class, annotated with "@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)", it loads the application, and the imported configuartion classes in the main class, are also loaded (that is MyConfiguration).

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
....
}
```

Is there a way to override the import, so that MyConfiguration is not loaded while running tests.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you need to use a SpringRunner but you want to use a different configuration. In that case you simply annotate your Test class with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeConfigurationClass.class)`

So it would look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeConfigurationClass.class)
public class MyTest {
....
}
```

If you do not want any Spring Container, just remove `@RunWith(...)`